# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.toString

Tags: android, json, scala

I am trying to parse a json String on android using with Scala

```
override def onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle): Unit = {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
 val jsonStr:String = Source.fromInputStream(getResources.openRawResource(R.raw.catalog)).mkString("")
 Log.i(TAG, jsonStr)
 val result = JSON.parseFull(jsonStr)
 result match {
   case Some(catalog) => Log.i(TAG, catalog.toString)
   case None => Toast.makeText(this, "cannot parse json", 2000).show();
 }
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid_view)
```

}

It compiles fine but when executed on android, it fails at JSON.parseFull with a runtime exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.toString

I am using scala 2.10.3

Seems like a bug with scala itself

Comment: nevermind. this is a known bug https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5397

Comment: The work around is to add "-keep class scala.collection.SeqLike {
    public protected *;
}" to proguard-rules.txt

Comment: is there any other way to fix this?