# Akka on Android

Tags: android, scala, akka, proguard

I have a problem with running akka on android. My App crashes once I start it. I use Akka 2.3.5, Scaloid 3.5-10.

I start my *SignInActivity* with

```
private implicit val system = ActorSystem("signin")  // this throws the error above
override def onCreate(savedState: Bundle): Unit = {
    super.onCreate(savedState)
    setContentView(R.layout.signin)
    val etMail = find[EditText](R.id.etMail)
    val etPass = find[EditText](R.id.etPass)
    find[Button](R.id.signInBtn).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener {
      override def onClick(v: View): Unit = {
        signIn(etMail.text.toString, etPass.text.toString)
      }
    })

09-21 11:35:34.601  10789-10789/at.itn.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: at.itn.android, PID: 10789
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$.empty
            at akka.actor.ActorCell$.<init>(ActorCell.scala:336)
            at akka.actor.ActorCell$.<clinit>(ActorCell.scala)
            at akka.actor.RootActorPath.$div(ActorPath.scala:159)
            at akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.<init>(ActorRefProvider.scala:464)
            at akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.<init>(ActorRefProvider.scala:452)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$2.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:78)
            at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191)
            at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:73)
            at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
            at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
            at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:230)
            at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
            at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.liftedTree1$1(ActorSystem.scala:584)
            at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:577)
            at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:141)
            at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:108)
            at at.itn.android.gui.activities.SignInActivity.<init>(SignInActivity.scala:20)
```

I dont really see how this definition could be of any trouble though. Maybe it's a *proguard.cfg* problem?

[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.toString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566031/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-scala-collection-immutable-stringlike-tostring)

Someone had a kind of similar problem and fixed it with some correct proguard options. I do have the SeqLike Part in my proguard, but maybe something else is missing.

Has anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong?

PS: I did make a similiar post before ([Akka on Android multiple reference.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25588841/akka-on-android-multiple-reference-conf) -  different akka problem though) , but since I couldn't get working until now I posted another akka question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can check the library dependencies by looking at the project pom file from Maven repository:

[Akka 2.3.5](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor_2.10/2.3.5/akka-actor_2.10-2.3.5.pom), [Scaloid 3.5-10](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/scaloid/scaloid_2.11/3.5-10/scaloid_2.11-3.5-10.pom)

You can see that Akka relies on scala-library 2.10.4 and Scaloid on 2.11.2.
If you want to use them in the same project/classpath, they need to have the same version of dependency libraries (ideal case) or have backward compatible versions, in order to avoid classpath clashes.